# In a geo div, how to add else show #other-country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a geo div, how to add else show {#other-country}?

I wish to hide CN and HK if the IP is other.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #CN {
      text-align: left;
      color: blue;
      display: none;
    }
    #HK {
      text-align: left;
      color: blue;
      display: none;
    }
    #country_code {
      text-align: left;
      color: blue;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="HK">Hello HK</div>
  <div id="CN">hello China</div>
  <div id="other-country">Hello Other country</div>
  <script>
    $.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(response) {
        $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
        if (response.country_code == 'HK' || response.country_code == 'CN') {
          document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
        }

      }

      , "jsonp");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have another question, can this put it in my own server?

http://freegeoip.net/json/

Answer (score 0):

Give all country code div a common class.

```
<div id="HK" class="country-code">Hello HK</div>
<div id="CN" class="country-code">hello China</div>
<div id="other-country" class="country-code">Hello Other country</div>

$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(response) {
    $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    document.querySelectorAll(".country-code").style.display = "none";
    if (response.country_code == 'HK' || response.country_code == 'CN') {
      document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
    }
   else{
      document.getElementById('other-country').style.display = "block";
   }

  }

  , "jsonp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer regarding @Prs answer - Just saw your post after "fiddling" with a similar idea :)

https://jsfiddle.net/kendrikat/b9hp434q/1/

HTML:

```
Hello
<div id="HK" class="country_code">HK</div>
<div id="DE" class="country_code">Germany</div>
<div id="OTHER" class="country_code">Other Country</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .country_code {
   text-align: left;
   color: blue;
   display: none;
 }
```

JS:

```
var countries_to_highlight = ['DE', 'HK'];

// hide them all - while loading
showCountry('', false)

$.get("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function(response) {

  if (countries_to_highlight.indexOf(response.country_code) > -1) {
    showCountry(response.country_code, true);
    showCountry('OTHER', false);
  } else {
    showCountry('OTHER', true);
    $('#OTHER.country_code').html(response.country_code);
  }

}, "jsonp");

function showCountry(tag, show) {
  $((tag.length > 0 ? '#' + tag : '') + '.country_code').css('display', show ? 'inline' : 'none')
}
```

Regarding you second question, if you are allowed to run it on your own server:

> The freegeoip web server is free and open source so if the public service limit is a problem for you, download it and run your own instance.

From their mainpage http://freegeoip.net/